# how to debug or run pytest scripts using eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pytest

i have installed the  [pytest framework](http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html).

i am able to run the testcases using the following command.

```
 py.test -q test_class.py
```

How to run the same test using eclipse?

Comment: Are you using PyDev? See http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html

Comment: Yes working fine by chaning the following settings Thanks.
From eclipse Window->Preferences -->PyUnit --> Change the Test runner to "Py.test runner".

Then select testcase (test_class.py) --> Run As --> Python Unit-Test

Comment: If you've solved the problem, you can write (and accept!) your own answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From eclipse Window->Preferences --> pydev --> PyUnit --> Change the Test runner to "Py.test runner".

Right Click over the file.
Run As --> Python Unit-Test

Or press Ctrl+F9:-

It will prompt you to select the test

Comment: if i run as python test , it is running as  python test_class.py.

Comment: Try Ctrl+F9. That would prompt you to select the class

Comment: @LavakuamrSangeetham :---  This didn't work as well??

Comment: I tried this but i am not able to select the Py.test runner using Ctrl+F9

Comment: It was working in my system. It will work! May need to change some preference settings in eclipse. not sure!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use pytest for a specific project

1. open the debug configurations (Menu -> Run -> Debug Configurations)
2. Select "Python unitest" and right click choosing "New Configuration"
3. In the "Name:" field pit something like "MyProject Py.Test"
4. In the "Project:" field click "Browse" and choose your project
5. In the "Main module" field click "Browse" and choose the main module for your project. This could be one specific file in your test suite or the tests folder for all of them.
6. Click the "Arguments" tab and check the "Override PyUnit preferences for this launch?" box.
7. Select "Py.test runner"
8. Click "Apply" and then click "Debug"

You can then run that configuration clicking on the little dropdown arrow next to the run menu or the debug menu and choosing the configuration to run (in this example "MyProject Py.Test")